# How to know the j-invariant of the modular elliptic curve from the modular form?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

How do people compute the $j$-invariant of an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb Q$ from the associated  modular form $f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nq^n$? In other words, how to compute (at least giving some estimates) $j(E)$ using $a_n$?

Comment: Silverman AEC.VIII.8.3 explains the minimal equation, this is an arithmetic choice of curve $E$. The $g_2,g_3$ of the lattice of the newform gives an analytic canonical choice $E'$. There is a 3rd one : from the maps $X_0(N)$ to $X_0(N)_{alg-\mathbb{Q}}$ to $J_0(N)_{alg-\mathbb{Q}}$ containing the algebraic canonical curve $E''$. I think the point is they know the latter Jacobian has good reduction for $p \nmid N$, they transfer it to $E''$, relating $E,E''$ outside of $p | N$. Then they probably make $X_0(N) \to J_0(N)_{alg-\mathbb{Q}}$ explicit.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a well-defined question, because the modular form $f$ corresponds to an isogeny class of elliptic curves, not a single elliptic curve; and the elliptic curves in the isogeny class can have different $j$-invariants.

However, if you ask for the $j$-invariant of some elliptic curve in the isogeny class, then this is a very well-studied problem, and there is an effective way of doing so using the period lattice. This is all described comprehensively and beautifully in John Cremona's book *Algorithms for modular elliptic curves* (available for free online [here](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/J.E.Cremona/book/fulltext/index.html)); the algorithm you're after is described in section 2.14.

Comment: If $f \in S_2(\Gamma_0(n))$ newform with rational coefficient and $F(p) = \int_{p_0}^p f(z)dz$ then $\gamma \mapsto F(\gamma(p_0))$ is an homomorphism $\Gamma_0(n) \to \mathbb{C}$ and its image is a lattice $ \Lambda=\omega_1\mathbb{Z}+\omega_2 \mathbb{Z}$. Is the section 2.10-14 taking some generators $\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_m$ of $\Gamma_0(n)/[\Gamma_0(n),\Gamma_0(n)]$ to find $\omega_1,\omega_2$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of the $F(\gamma_l(p_0))$ ? Then that $g_2(\Lambda) ,g_3(\Lambda) $ are (almost) integers is something about minimal models given $j(\Lambda) \in \mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Thank you very much! So one can only get an abelian variety up to isogeny? But it seems in chapter 10 section 2 at https://www.wstein.org/edu/Fall2003/252/lectures/all/252.pdf, one can multiply positive integer $n$ to get a real abelian variety $A_f$

Comment: @zzy $E,E', u:E \to E',u^*u = m$ elliptic curves and pair of dual isogeny everything  defined over a same number field. For almost all primes  :  everything has good reduction so the curves $\tilde{E},\tilde{E}'$ are isogeneous and their Frobenius $\phi,\phi'$ satisfy $u^* \phi' = \phi u^*,  \phi'u  =u\phi,u^*\phi u = m\phi$ so $\phi'^2-t'\phi'+q=0$ means $0=u^*\phi'^2u-t'u^*\phi'u+u^*qu =\phi^2 m - t' m \phi+qm = 0$ so $t' = t$. Whence $L(s,E) = L(s,E')$ up to finitely many primes, and the corresponding modular forms have the same newform representative.

Comment: @reuns Thank you! But I think somehow there is a canonical choice for the elliptic curve?